# Login url gets changed on redirection with authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using **owin custom authentication** and **asp.net identity** and have login url like this:

```
http://localhost:1927/
```

Now after login user will be redirected to dashboard page and url will be like this:

```
http://localhost:1927/Dashboard/Index
```

Now after user logout i am redirecting user to login page and url is still fine like below:

http://localhost:1927/

But now when i enter this url  `http://localhost:1927/Dashboard/Index` directly in browser then i am again redirecting to login
page and url changes to below url:

```
http://localhost:1927/Authentication/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FDashboard%2FIndex
```

I know this is because i have decorated both my `Authentication and Dashboard controller` with `Authorize attribute`.

Code:

```
[Authorize]
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {

    }

     [Authorize]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {

    }

public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login")
            });
            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        }
    }
```

**Web.config:**

```
 <authentication mode="None" />

  <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
```

So is it possible to have url like below on redirecting to login page:

```
http://localhost:1927/
```

If yes then how??

Comment: If you were using a SPA framework then that would be easy. But the URL is a resource locator, to remove the part that said where to go for authorisation is like, working against the grain

Comment: @CallumLinington :I am not using SPA framework.Routing will be handles by mvc routing only

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that... So you'll be working against the grain